# Why does this signalr interface method not need a proper implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, interface, signalr

Can't wrap my head around this piece of code of an example.

There is an interface that looks like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NotificationHub
{
    public interface INotifyHubClient
    {
        Task NotifyClient(string type);
    }
}
```

And a class that uses the interface:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace NotificationHub
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotifyHubClient>
    {
    }
}
```

In a controller it is simply used like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;

namespace NotificationHub.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class NotificationController : Controller
    {
        private IHubContext<NotificationHub, INotifyHubClient> _hubContext;

        public NotificationController(IHubContext<NotificationHub, INotifyHubClient> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody]string message)
        {
            _hubContext.Clients.All.NotifyClient(message);
            return "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this work without a proper implementation for NotifyClient?

Comment: You mean there is no class in the project which implements `INotifyHubClient` interface?

Comment: Yeah, the NotificationHub implements the Hub<INotifyHubClient> but whats happening with the NotifyClient-Method from the INotifyHubClient...

Comment: "_whats happening with the NotifyClient-Method from the INotifyHubClient_" Well, some instantiable type (class) implements the INotifyHubClient, for sure. So, your controller gets some hubContext injected, and that hubContext provides access to an instance of whatever type is implementing the INotifyHubClient interface. Why exactly can't you wrap your head around that?

Comment: Yeah, but where does this happen? I mean I defined the NotifyClient-Method - it could be anything else like `Task ThisIsAFunnyName(bool someBool)` and it would just work even though there IS no implementation for the interface method. I surely have the feeling, that I am missing something elementary here, so I hoped, someone could clear it for me, because I could not find an explanation.

Comment: `NotifyClient` method is implemented internally by the generic hub (`Hub<INotifyHubClient>`) using reflection: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hub%60T.cs, https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/TypedClientBuilder.cs